# Eloquent Relationships - hasOneThrough relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, has-one-through

**Question**
I want to get the matching `schedule` from it's table for an `availability`, using the `shift_id` in the `availabilities` table.
Availabilities is already a pivot table between `users` and `shifts`.

I thought a hasOneThrough relation is the way to go here, but i can't seem to get it to work.
What am I doing wrong?

**Tables**

Availabilities
- id
- user_id
- shift_id
- ...

Shifts
- id
- schedule_id
- ...

Schedules
- id
- ...

**The Availability model**

```
 public function schedule()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        'App\Schedule',
        'App\Shift',
        'schedule_id',
        'id',
        'shift_id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

**Problem**
Somehow when I use PHP Artisan Tinker I get the schedule with id of Availability.id instead of the schedule with the id of shift.id.
Since this schedule does not exist, i get an

> $availability = App\Availability::find(1331);
>   $availability→schedule()→get();
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3111
>    all: [],
>   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying and inspecting the generated sql queries, I came to the conclusion that hasOneThrough can not be used in this way.

I used a querybuilder instead:

```
   public function schedule()
 {
     return DB::table('schedules')
         ->join('shifts', 'shifts.schedule_id', '=', 'schedules.id')
         ->where('shifts.id', '=', "$this->shift_id")
         ->select('schedules.*', 'shifts.schedule_id')
         ->get();
 }
```

Comment: I got frustrated with `hasOneThrough` also, so I ended up just using `belongsTo` twice, i.e., `$availability->shift->schedule`. This would save the hassle of building a custom query.

Answer (score 0):

i think you reverse your relation on hasOneThrough so the relation should be :

```
 public function schedule()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        'App\Shift',
        'App\Schedule',
        'shift_id',
        'schedule_id',

    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This didn't work too.

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'schedules.shift_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `shifts`.*, `schedules`.`shift_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `shifts` inner join `schedules` on `schedules`.`id` = `shifts`.`schedule_id` where `schedules`.`shift_id` = 1331)'.

Found solution today:

         return DB::table('schedules')
             ->join('shifts', 'shifts.schedule_id', '=', 'schedules.id')
             ->where('shifts.id', '=', "$this->shift_id")
             ->select('schedules.*', 'shifts.schedule_id')
             ->get();